# How can I echo SQL data from database table into a <select> form?

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, select-options

i would like to `echo` some SQL data into a `<select>` form with each  as a different row from the table.

**i have a table:-**

```
repair (repair_id , date , machine_name ,Machine_vin , request , adresss);
```

and i would like to have the `Machine_vin` numbers to come in the select options.. and each time one is removed or added it reflects in the option.

am stumped on code, only have:

```
    <?php 
       $sql = "select * from repair";
       $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
       $selectResult="";
       while($list = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
       $Machine_vin  = $list['Machine_vin'];

       $selectResult.="<option value="$Machine_vin">$Machine_vin</option>";

    ?>
```

get a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$Machine_vin'

how do i reflect the `machine_vins` in the  `<select>` option.

Comment: Show what code you have tried.

Comment: @costelle have you tried my updated answer????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should update your question with something you have tried. Even a piece of code you tried to accomplish your goal.When you need to `fetch` data and add those data into a drop down you can follow below steps.

1.Fetch data from DB.

2.Assign each of data into drop down options with a `while` loop

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Machine_vin numbers </label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select  class="form-control"  name="machine_vin" required>
            <option  value="0" selected disabled>Select the type of Machine vin number</option>
            <?php
             //fetch data from db
            $sql_machine_vin = ' SELECT * FROM  repair';
             // query the sql with db connection           
            $result_machine_vin = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_machine_vin);
             //loop the result
            while($row_machine_vin =mysqli_fetch_array($result_machine_vin)){
            ?>

             <option  value="<?=$row_machine_vin['Machine_vin'];?>" >
             <?=$row_machine_vin['Machine_vin'];?> ></option>
             <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>>
```

Comment: thank you... returns 'undefined index : Machine_vin " at options part, and id only like to fetch the machine_vin and not the repair_id

Comment: @Nipun op wants the Machine_vin  in option value Attribute.

Comment: @Costelle I have updated my answer. Please remove white spaces iside echo if there are any. Also if it still generate errors please let us know

Comment: @NipunTharuksha the op gets "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file".

Comment: @MohitKumar sorry one of  **>** was missing in the code . Please check it now

Comment: works now !! thank you! messed with my css a little but i think i can figure that out .. thank you again!!!

Comment: @Costelle please chenge and check ` <?=$row_machine_vin['Machine_vin'];?>` to  <?=$row_machine_vin['machine_name'];?>` please let us know what it return

Comment: @Costelle nice to hear that. It would be great if you could give some upvotes for our answers too. Thanks

Comment: @NipunTharuksha how do i give upvotes?.. its actually perfect with machine_vin

Comment: @Costelle sorry I cant understand. Also its better if you could save a id instead of a name and then through that id you can retrive data

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
  $sql = "select * from repair";
  $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  $selectResult="";
  while($list = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    $Machine_vin  = $list['Machine_vin'];

    $selectResult.="<option value='$Machine_vin'>$Machine_vin</option>";

    ?>
<form method='post' action='#'>
<select name="course">
   <option value="0">Please Select Option</option>
      <?php echo $Machine_vin; ?>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for response.. i get a "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$Machine_vin' (T_VARIABLE)" on the $selectResult part

Comment: @Costelle see my updated answer please,  and please change "$Machine_vin" to '$Machine_vin'

Comment: i get "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file".. maybe that may be cause i have php that sends to db?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are new to PHP and MySQL
for starters you can start reading this:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

To get the data and parse it through PHP is like this:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Then you play with your output buffer ECHO scripts and render the tags you want them to put in to.

Comment: you're welcome :)